# Input-group-addon is not intact to the input text

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

My input group add on is not intact to the text. Can someone help me about this?

Here is the output
[image]

here is my style.

```
<style>
   .dates{
    width: 200px !important;
    margin-left: 500px;
    }
 </style>
```

here is the code for date

```
        <div class="form-group">
               <label for="title">Date</label>
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control dates" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> 
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Correct me If I am wrong because I don't know the context exactly. Is this necessary to set input 200px wide ?

If you really want to set input width to a specific value, It must be in the container of input-group.

```css
.form-group-wrapper {
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-group-wrapper">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Date</label>
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control dates" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise I suggest you to use bootstrap grid system to make it easier like so.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Date</label>
        <div class='input-group' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```